# MySQL Workbench table organisation

Tags: mysql-workbench

Well, I'm interested is there a way to (someway)automatically organize database tables when you make EER Model from existing database.

In my schema I have 30(and something) tables and 50(and something) relationships and when I do thing noted above all my tables are placed on one spot. So, you could imagine how would it look with bigger schema. This is how it looks in my situation:

[image]

Also, I know that there is Arrange on the menu bar but it doesn't give much option.

I'm using 5.2.44 CE version of MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Model -> Diagram Properties and Size and increase the number of pages for the model
2. Select Arrange -> AutoLayout which evenly spreads out the tables in the model.

You can repeat the above as you add more pages to get the best fit